# Share limited number of resources across multiple threads having difference priority

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have some resources shared by multiple threads. Each resources can only be accessed by one thread at a time.

I use a `Queue` to store resources:

```
import queue
import threading

class SharedResource:
    def __init__(self):
        self._resources = queue.Queue()
        self._resources.put('resources_1')
        self._resources.put('resources_2')

    def access(self):
        r = self._resources.get()
        #  Do some works.
        print('access ' + r)
        self._resources.put(r)


resources = SharedResource()


def work():
    resources.access()

threads = [threading.Thread(target=work) for _ in range(5)]
[t.start() for t in threads]
```

Now there are some threads having priorities over other ones. The threads with higher priorities should get the resources first when the resources are available.

I think I could add a method `access_first`, which will be called by the threads with higher priorities, and a *multiple readers/**multiple** writer lock*  to `SharedResource`. `access` will acquire the lock as a reader, and `access_first` will acquire the lock as a writer.

My Questions are:

1. Is it a good idea to use `Queue` to store the shared resources?
2. If there are multiple levels of priority for threads, how can I implement  `access` to make sure that threads with higher priorities will get the resources first?